# Highlighting multiple dates on jquery ui datepicker calendar works fine when clicking directly, but not when triggered by external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I'm using the following to create a calendar that I can select multiple days for. It stores which days are turned "on" by using an object with values set to 1/0 true/false based on which days are selected.

Then I have a function that adds a "selected" class to each day that is turned on. It works flawlessly when I'm clicking dates manually, but I created buttons to select specific days (or date ranges later if I can get this working), but for some reason the code that highlights the days only works when clicking directly and not when using the buttons.

What the actual freck is going on?

```js
                <div id="days_cal_area">
                    <div id="days_cal"></div>
                    <div id="last_day" >Last</div>
                </div>

                <script>    
                    // Maintain array of dates
                    var days = {};

                    $('#days_cal').datepicker({
                        inline: true,
                        firstDay: 0,
                        showOtherMonths: false,
                        selectOtherMonths: false,
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        changeYear: false,
                        defaultDate: new Date(1995, 0, 1),
                        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                            day = parseInt(dateText.split('-')[2])
                            days[day] = !days[day];
                            daysStr();
                        },
                        beforeShowDay: function (date) {

                            var day = date.getDate();

                            if (days[day]) 
                                return [true, " date_selected day_"+day];
                            return [true, "day_"+day];
                        }
                    });     
                </script>
                <div class="button_area row_items days_buttons">
                    <div class="sm_button" select="1" type="day">The 1st</div>
                    <div class="sm_button" select="15" type="day">The 15th</div>
                    <div class="sm_button" id='last_button'>Last day</div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden_field">
                    <?php $task_form->write_fields(['days','weekdays','weeks','months']); ?>
                </div>

                <script>

                    function daysStr(){
                        console.log(days);
                        // Clear selected days
                        $('#days_cal .date_selected').removeClass('date_selected');

                        // Build a string for the form
                        temp = [];
                        $.each(days,function(day,addIt){
                            if (addIt) {
                                // Add it to the string for form submission
                                temp.push(day);
                                // Also mark it on the calendar
                                $('[data-day='+day+']').addClass('date_selected');
                            }
                        })
                        // Now add it to the form
                        $('#days_area [name=days]').val(temp.join(','));
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        // prep the calendar (ONE TIMEM THINGS)
                            $('#days_area a').each(function(){
                                theTD = $(this).closest('td');
                                day = $(this).text();
                                $(theTD).data('day',day);
                            })

                        $('#days_area [type=day]').click(function(){
                            tempDays = $(this).attr('select').split(',');   // Comma list of days
                            $(tempDays).each(function(index,day){
                                days[day] = true;
                            })
                            daysStr();
                        })

                        $('#last_button').click(function(){
                            $(this).toggleClass('on');
                            if ($(this).hasClass('on')){ 
                                $('#last_day').show(); 
                                days['last'] = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#last_day').hide();
                                days['last'] = false;
                            }
                            daysStr();
                        })

                    })

                </script>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of references to elements that do not appear in your example code. It's also not clear what is not working here versus what it should be doing.

Comment: We also need an example of the date data.